# Prove that: $D:C^1[a,b]\rightarrow C[a,b]$ defined by $Df=f'$ isn't continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that:

$$D:(C^1[a,b],||.||_\infty)\rightarrow (C[a,b],||.||_\infty)$$

defined by $Df=f'$ isn't continuous.

**My attempt:**

I'm trying to prove that $D$ is not bounded but i'm stuck by this way

$\forall M>0\,,\exists t\in[a,b]$ such that $||(Df)(t)||>M.||f'(t)||$

Moreover i know that $(C^1[a,b],||.||_\infty)$ isn't a banach space.

Comment: I guess you meant $$\Vert Df \Vert_\infty > M \Vert f\Vert_\infty$$ without any $t$ floating around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, let's take $[a,b]=[0,1]$. If you consider the sequence $f_n(t)=t^n,$ then $Df_n(t)=nt^{n-1},$ and so $$\frac{\|Df_n\|_{\infty}}{\|f_n\|_\infty}=n.$$ Can you see why this shows that $D$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 3):

Apply $D$ to $e^{Mt}$. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to find a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (C^1[a,b], \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty})$ with $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \Vert f_n \Vert = 1$ s.t. the sequence $(Df_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (C^1[a,b], \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty})$ is not bounded.

If one can show that, then there does not exists a $C> 0$ s.t. $\Vert Df_n \Vert \leq C \Vert f_n \Vert$. So consider $f_n(x):= \frac{e^{nx}}{e^{nb}}$. Then we have $\Vert f_n \Vert_{\infty} = 1$ and $Df_n(x) = n f_n(x)$. Hence we have $\Vert Df_n \Vert_{\infty} = n$ which gives the result.